# How do I fix the alignment issues in my table to conform to material design guidelines?

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design, materialize

In https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-specs there's recommendations on how to have proper column padding.

See below [image]

I am using materializecss v0.100.2 to setup a datatable with checkboxes. It looks like this now.

This is my codepen on what I have done so far.

https://codepen.io/tj_simmons/pen/OzyapG

```js
/**
 * start of responsive side menu
 */
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
/**
 * end of responsive side menu
 */
/**
 * start of checkbox-table
 */
jQuery(function($) {
  $("td input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function (e) {
    console.log('change');
    row = $(this).closest('tr');
    console.log(row);
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        row.addClass('selected');
    } else {
        row.removeClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
/**
 * end of checkbox 
 */
```

```css
/**
 * start of responsive-side-menu
 */
/**
 * Body CSS
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

html,
body,
input,
textarea,
buttons {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
}


/**
 * Layout CSS
 */

 header, main, footer {
   padding-left: 300px;
 }

 /**
  * fix the left align for brand-logo
  */
 nav {
   width: calc(100% - 300px);
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
   header, main, footer {
     padding-left: 0;
   }
   nav {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }


/**
 * helper Classes
 */
.no-margin {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
/**
 * end of responsive-side-menu
 */
/**
 * start of checkbox-color
 */
.checkbox-pink[type="checkbox"] + label:before{
  background: transparent;
}
.checkbox-pink[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before{
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ec407a;
  border-right: 2px solid #ec407a;
  background: transparent;
}
.checkbox-pink.filled-in[type="checkbox"] + label:after{
  background: transparent;
}
.checkbox-pink.filled-in[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after{
  background: #ec407a;
  border: 2px solid #ec407a;
}
.checkbox-pink.filled-in[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before{
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
/**
 * end of checkbox color
 */
/**
 * start of table colors
 */
/**
 * because certain materializecss does not abide by material.io guidelines
 * See https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-interaction
 * and https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2262
 */
 table.striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #eeeeee !important;
 }

 table.highlight > tbody > tr:hover {
   background-color: #eeeeee !important;
 }

 table > tbody > tr.selected {
   background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
}
/**
 * end of table colors
 */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <header>
        <div class="navbar-fixed">
          <nav class="blue" role="navigation">
              <div class="nav-wrapper container">
                <a href="!#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse left no-margin"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <a class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a id="" href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a id="" href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav fixed">
            <li><a id="" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a id="" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div class="container">

          <div class="section">
            <h3 class="blue-text">Table with checkbox</h3>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12" class="flow-text">
                <div class="card-panel">
                  <table class="highlight">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th class="valign-wrapper">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in checkbox-pink" id="all" />
                            <label for="all"></label>
                          </th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Item Name</th>
                          <th>Item Price</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="valign-wrapper">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in checkbox-pink" id="checkbox1" />
                          <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>Alvin</td>
                        <td>Eclair</td>
                        <td>$0.87</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="valign-wrapper">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in checkbox-pink" id="checkbox2" />
                          <label for="checkbox2"></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>Alan</td>
                        <td>Jellybean</td>
                        <td>$3.76</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="valign-wrapper">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in checkbox-pink" id="checkbox3" />
                          <label for="checkbox3"></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>Jonathan</td>
                        <td>Lollipop</td>
                        <td>$7.00</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </main>


      <footer class="page-footer blue">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col l6 s12">
              <h5 class="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
              <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
              <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
          <div class="container">
          Made with ♥ by BusinessCoder
          <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

Help me to understand how I can achieve what the guidelines is asking.

I am eyeballing but it appears that my padding for the columns is not correct.

How do I check that I am confirming to the standards for padding correctly and how to correct?

Comment: It appears you left out the most important part: **what is it** you do not understand?

Comment: I am eyeballing but it seems that the padding is not conforming to the guidelines.

Comment: Materialize.css **is not** developed by Google. It's a jQuery-fication of Material Design developed by [4 students](http://materializecss.com/about.html#team). If you want the real deal in terms of MD principles (motion, poetry, intention, purpose) use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/).

Comment: I am not as familiar with angular as jquery. I’ll take a look at angular material more deeply but from the looks of it I will have to build my own datatable with checkbox from scratch just like with materializecss

Comment: It's not a small task, but you can reverse engineer most of the CSS behind Angular Material.

Comment: I guess I have to. Materializecss wasn’t perfect either I also had to override some of their changes using a mixture of js and css. Thanks for the tip. By the way this may be slightly digressing but is there a way to visually see how the containers are aligned in my own data table just like the screenshot I attached ? I don’t trust my own eyeballs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using HTML tables for your layout, your columns are each of your `<td>` elements. Right now, it looks like there is only 5px of padding on the inside of each `<td>`, giving a total of 10px between each column.

Maybe you can try increasing the padding to a pixel amount that will be greater than 56dp to meet the minimum requirement for space between columns.

The checkboxes `<td>` cells may also need more padding so that the height of the checkbox is no larger than 75% of the height of the parent (18db of 24db).